# How to expose value from Child to Parent component with useImperativeHandle and show current value

Tags: reactjs

I have a Parent component that has uses `useRef` for a Child component, which is created with `forwardRef`, see here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lxawy3?file=src%2FApp.js

If the user clicks on the button, the value of `counter` is incremented in the Child component state, but it is always one step ahead of what is showing for that exposed value in the Parent component.

I understand that `useState` updates are asynchronous but I was under the impression that triggering a state update in the Parent will refresh the value. What I would like to achieve is to have the Parent have access to the current, up to date value of counter inside the Child.

Answer (score 0):

The setCounter was called correctly, but React state updates are asynchronous and when you try to re-render using updateState({}), counter state of Child was not updated.

After that, when the `childRef.current?.counter` is updated, React does not re-render your Parent component. So it will retain previous value.

You can confirm it in the following updates. It will show the same values.

```
const increment = () => {
    childRef.current.increment();
    setTimeout(() => {
      updateState({});
    }, 1)
};
```

You can resolve this.

- Pass a callback prop to Child and notify Parent of new states value when the Child state changes using useEffect.
- Share states via props between Parent and Child
- Use application state

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Shared state and app state will not be a good fit for what I am trying to do, but let me try a callback prop with `useEffect`.